# Can't find scripting engine for 'LiferayJavaScript

Tags: liferay, activiti

I am creating a workflow i.e. `single-approval-definition` in activiti and this workflow is added to Liferay. In this workflow I am using a script task. The script task uses `LiferayJavascript` to change the status of the review process from `pending` to `approved`. When I am trying to complete this task with the help of the REST API then it is showing the following error:

```
"errorMessage":"Can't find scripting engine for 'LiferayJavaScript'",
"statusCode":500
```

My script is like this:

```
Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStat‌​us(
    Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approv‌​ed"), 
    workflowContext);
```

When i use `javascript` instead of `LiferayJavascript` then it is showing the following error:

```
"errorMessage":"problem evaluating script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: \"workflowContext\" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1",
"statusCode":500
```

Comment: Just a guess: use `javascript` instead of `LiferayJavascript`. And add the relevant code snippets to your questions, always, ever.

Comment: myscript is like this : Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);                                   when i using javascript instead of LiferayJavascript then it is showing the following error :   "errorMessage":"problem evaluating script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: \"workflowContext\" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1","statusCode":500

Comment: Here on stackoverflow we try to improve questions and answers by editing the original posts. I've integrated that information for you now. Did you try to start the workflow from the Liferay UI as well?

Comment: thank you for this help... yes, i also tried to start the workflow with liferay UI but it is showing the following error : "My Workflow Tasks is temporarily unavailable" in Liferay UI.  and when i tried with rest then it is showing the following error : "errorMessage":"problem evaluating script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(number,string). (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1","statusCode":500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for my question and i am here to share it with you. I use the Javascript instead of LiferayJavascript. I was getting error :

```
"errorMessage":"problem evaluating script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: \"workflowContext\" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1",
"statusCode":500
```

To remove this error, i copy Rhino.jar in activiti-explorer's lib, rest-lib's as well as the tomcat's lib.
I changed my script from

```
Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStat‌​us(
    Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approv‌​ed"), 
    workflowContext);
```

to:

```
Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"),execution.getVariables())
```

and my problem get resolved. :-)